# Finding maximum bipartite matching

Tags: algorithms, graphs, bipartite-matching

I read an article https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/ to solve the maximum bipartite problem. In this article, two solutions are given.

In the first solution, they have explained that we can use edmond-karp algorithm to find the maximum bipartite matching and that would take $O(|E|^2|V|)$ and then there's an another solution given which works in $O(|E||V|)$.

Moreover, if there are problems like a job can be given to multiple people or a person can do multiple jobs can also be done using both methods.

I read over many online resources and the first method seems to be quite popular. So, are there any problems where I would want to use the first method over the second method?

Comment: Check out [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs).